# Tag selection clears SE site selection on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Time and again I'll create a question on the Android app, only to find I'm asked which SE site... Despite already selecting this first.

It seems like the tag selection goes right to site selection even if site is already selected?

Comment: Good luck with getting this fixed. Apps been dead since 2017

Comment: So why is this not publicised in the app, or the app revived from the stores?

Comment: Because its dead

Comment: They haven't bothered

Comment: It's normal to notify users an app is deprecated.

Comment: Well it's not even on the play store anymore :P

Comment: It was when I installed it!